# Center div between middle and left

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I have a logo aligned in the center, and when I adjust the screen/window width it keeps in the center perfectly. To the left of the logo I have a small menu with only two words, I want this menu/div to always be between the logo and the left edge.

Can this be done with only CSS?

To consider is that the logo has its own widht `200px` but I can fix this with `margin-left: -100px;`.
And when it comes down to a screen size where it no longer fits to the left!, I will put it under the logo with `@media screen and (max-width: px) { ... }`.

Like this: http://postimg.org/image/v148gyc9b/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the logo has a fixed size of 200px, **you can try something like this** :

```
#menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: calc(50% - 100px);
}
```

Comment: Yes. I only needed the width: calc(50% - 100px) for the menu, and I could remove the margin-left: -100px; I had for the logo!

I will test this a bit but it look like it should work!
Any idea about the browser support the the calc?

Thank you!